# Where are all the new features in 2.79B?

Tags: node-editor, shaders, displacement

Where is the new principled-volume shader, the displacement node, and the random-walk falloff in the subsurface node? These features are in the 2.79 nightly build but not the latest release.

Comment: 2.79B is a maintenance release, meaning only bug fixes, no new features

Comment: Anyone knows why the documentation for 2.79 shows those new feature but they do appear in any of the 2.79 releases? ex: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/materials/displacement.html

Comment: Apparently the manual targets the nightly builds. I'm not sure that's a great idea, but as far as I can tell that's what the doc writers decided to do.

Comment: I was really hoping for the random walk falloff. Sad that it will be only added in a future release, maybe 2.8. Now that I think of it my computer does not support openGL 3.